# Power BI - Getting invalid date ranges when creating a date table in DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, calendar

I'm trying to create a Date table in Power BI using DAX. The formula I used is:

```
Date = ADDCOLUMNS( CALENDAR("1/1/1994","12/31/2024"),
        "Year", YEAR([Date]),
        "Month Number", MONTH([Date]),
        "Month", FORMAT([Date],"mmmm"),
        "Quarter", FORMAT([Date],"\QQ")    
        )
```

So `Calendar` function has 2 arguments, start date and end date. You can see above that the start date is 1/1/1994 and the end date is 12/31/2024.  However, when I look at the results of the data table, the start date is 7/1/1994 and the end date is 1/31/2023.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Columns in the screenshot do not match formula. Are you sure you are looking at the correct place?

Comment: @pkExec I updated the page, but the result still ends in error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the dropdown of the Date column and then **Sort ascending**

[image]

Comment: Please feed back: Did the answer help to solve the issue or not? What's missing?